# Сортировка List Java

Tags: java, list

Имеется list с несколькими значениями. Необходимо сделать так, чтобы одно из значений всегда находилось внизу списка, независимо от того, чему равны предыдущие. К примеру, у нас есть 3 числа (20, 12 и 68). Нужно сделать так, чтобы число 68 всегда находилось внизу, независимо от того, чему равны предыдущие числа.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3962766/how-to-reverse-a-list-in-java

Comment: `for (int i = list.size-1; i >= 0; i--) System.out.println(list.get(i));` ?

Comment: это не совсем то, что хотелось)

Comment: @АртемПотешкин зато отвечает полностью на вашу формулировку вопроса (`вывести list в обратном порядке`). Постарайтесь хотя бы точнее мысли выразить, не говоря уже о кусках кода и ваших попытках.

Comment: Прошу прощения.

Comment: @АртемПотешкин не надо просить прощения, меня вы ничем не обидели — но вы делаете себе хуже, не пытаясь самостоятельно и не предоставляя нормальной возможности оценить вашу проблему и помочь вам. Я, например, так и не понял, чего вы хотели.

Comment: У меня есть 3 числа. Нужно сделать так, чтобы одно из них всегда было внизу списка, независимо от того, какие перед ним стоят числа.

Comment: @АртемПотешкин постарайтесь более точно сформулировать проблему и дополните свой вопрос. Писать пояснения в комментарии не стоит, ибо не все могут их заметить, а вопрос будут минусовать за плохую формулировку.

Comment: Мда, пока писал ответ, поменялась вся суть вопроса. Не надо так

Comment: Вот, то, о чём я и говорил.

Comment: Исправил вопрос

Comment: А причём тут сортировка? (Да, я вижу предыдущие версии, но ни одна версия, ни их совокупность не объясняет задачи)

Comment: @АртемПотешкин, сохраняйте "особенные числа" в отельный массив, опишите метод обработки исходного массива. Метод будет удалять числа, которые есть в массиве "особенных чисел" и в конце вставлять их в самый конец исходного

Comment: И опять же, непонятно, что происходит с исходным массивом? Во время какой-то обработки нужно не трогать конкретный элемент? Или элемент, равный какому-то значению? Или элемент на указанной позиции? Что это за обработка? Сортировка? В общем, вопрос составлен абсолютно никак

Comment: Я услышал много отличной критики. Но, друзья, я новичок, и возможно у меня есть какие-то промахи. Я могу где-то неправильно объяснить. Спасибо за внимание. Вопрос закрыт.

Comment: Используйте Map, ключом будет приоритет. Для все, кто должен быть "внизу", задавайте низкий приоритет, остальным повыше... Ну а дальше в зависимости от задачи - пишите compare(), equals() итд, который подходит для вашей задачи. Как-то так.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как то так:

```
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.Comparator;
    import java.util.List;

    public class ListSorter {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            sort(Arrays.asList(20, 12, 68));
            sort(Arrays.asList(-5, 800, 68));
            sort(Arrays.asList(100, 14, 68));
        }

        private static void sort(List<Integer> integers) {
            final int max = 68;

            Collections.sort(integers, new Comparator<Integer>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
                    int res;
                    if (o1 == max) {
                        res = 1;
                    } else {

                        res = o1.compareTo(o2);
                    }
                    return res;
                }
            });

            System.out.println(integers);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Если лист объектов, то можно использовать схему:

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Object>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        return o1.getProperty().compareTo(o2.getProperty());
});
```

Comment: А если мне нужно сравнивать с заданным числом, к примеру у меня есть число 20, и числа 15 и 35. Можно сделать так, чтобы они сравнивались с 20 и 20 всегда была внизу? В каком порядке будут числа 15 и 35 не важно.

Comment: @АртемПотешкин, compare возвращает положение левого элемента (o1) относительно правого (o2). Положение может быть отрицательным (-1), - значит слева, нулевым (0), - значит что оба элемента равны между собой и их порядок можно не менять и положительным (1), - значит что левый элемент надо переместить вправо